# Is it possible to reference the baseline of the lowest line in multiline node with an arbitrary number of lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, baseline

## Question

Can I automatically reference the lowest baseline of a node in TikZ?

### Situation

I would like to draw a line under the lowest baseline of the node in red (*not just `moonfact.south west` -- `moonfact.south east`*).

### Example Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline,every node/.style={draw,red,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]%
    \node [align=left,text width=5em] (moonfact) {The moon is 384,400 kilometers away from earth.};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]%
    \draw ([yshift=-1ex]moonfact.base west) -- ([yshift=-1ex]moonfact.base east);
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

### Output as standalone with a border of 10px

[image]

Compare the two examples both with `anchor=north` and using `south west` and `south east` instead of `base west` and `base east`. The g affects the line distance. It would be nice to avoid this with the use of a "last-line baseline":

[image]

Comment: You want to draw the line under earth then? I think a three-part node would be much more efficient

Comment: In your last two cases listed, add ing a `\strut` to the end of the input will cause the two black lines to align.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps but, introducing a `\strut` after every node text will adjust bottom node's limit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,baseline,every node/.style={draw,red,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt}]%
    \node [align=left,text width=5em] (moonfact) {The moon is 384,400 kilometers away from earth.\strut};
    \node [align=left,text width=5em,anchor=north west,at=(moonfact.north east)] (car) {My car is forty meters away from my garage.\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,baseline]%
    \draw ([yshift=-1ex]moonfact.south west) -- ([yshift=-1ex]moonfact.south east);
    \draw[blue] ([yshift=-1ex]car.south west) -- ([yshift=-1ex]car.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome Ignasi! That will definitely help. I am going to leave the question open a while longer, but you provided an effective workaround.